# How to Export a Single .fbx animation (w/ workflow to Unreal UE4/5)

Tags: .fbx, unreal-engine

How do I export a single animation in Blender in .fbx format?
I have a model with a bunch of mesh+rig+animations+blendspaces, but just want the single animation to be exported not the whole setup.

*So I was facing huge export (45 + mins) and import times (to UE5)(45 + mins) of a .fbx file in Blender 2.7->3.0,*
*[Context: Hardware - AMD 5950x + GeForce 3090, Model - 100,000 vertices + 10 Materials, Blender 3.0 -> UE4/5 workflow]*
*As I was exporting the whole mesh+rig+animations+blendspaces...*

This guide (+ alittle help from a friend)helped me figure this out:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/603212/how-to-import-single-animation-made-in-blender.html
it has all the info there, albeit alittle messy IMO, so i thought i would try to say it succinctly.

I hope this helps me remember and maybe someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start fresh.
Object Mode(But you can be in Pose or whatever). Select nothing.
Open up both the non linear editor, and the dopesheet-actioneditor:

Select the animation in the action_editor,
[image]
(on the DopeSheet make sure that all other NLA Rows are NOT selected by the checkbox.)
[image]
Press the "Push Down Action" Button.
(If you are making multiple animations in one session, make sure that the you always make a new animation, or that your NLA Row is always at the the top of the currently selected rig's rows, as it appears to take the top of the stack.)
[image]
You should see see only just the animation that you want, and the rig selected in the NLA window.
*Don't need anything selected in the "Viewport", or in the "Outline tree Hierarchy".*
File->Export->.fbx
Pick these settings:
[image]
(Scale & transform * bone alignment to your specifics, this is not a guide for that)
(Make sure that "All Actions", and "NLA Strip" are unchecked!!
Export.

For Unreal UE4/5 workflow.
Make sure that you select your skeleton is selected in the import options, and I used default animation settings, no other import settings are applicable to this workflow guide.
Import.